# Series of gamma function with fixed real part and increasing imaginary part

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

I'm trying to evaluate the series or to pursue a upper bound, theoretically or numerically:
$$
\sum_{k \ge 1} \left|  \Gamma(m+2\pi ik/\log q) \right|
$$
I know this series is convergent because each term decreases exponentially with k.
I tried it with Mathematica, but it says no.
And I have done the case with $m=-1,q=2$ here [A Fourier series' upper bound involving gamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084281/a-fourier-series-upper-bound-involving-gamma-function).
Anyone knows about the universal mean?
Thank you for consideration!

Comment: Now I am using a stupid method to add up the sum. I don't add for k to infinity. Instead, I add up for k to 1000. And $ \left|  \Gamma(m+2\pi ik/\log q) \right| $ is less than $1e^{-1000}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $y=\frac{2\pi}{\log\left(q\right)}
 $. Using Stirling approximation we have $$\left|\Gamma\left(m+iky\right)\right|\sim\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-\pi k\left|y\right|/2}\left(k\left|y\right|\right)^{m-1/2}
 $$ and so $$\sum_{k\geq1}\left|\Gamma\left(m+i\frac{2\pi k}{\log\left(q\right)}\right)\right|\sim\frac{2^{m}\pi^{m}}{\log\left(q\right)^{m-1/2}}\sum_{k\geq1}e^{-\pi^{2}k/\log\left(q\right)}k^{m-1/2}
 $$ and the series converges if $\log\left(q\right)>0
 $. To complete te proof note $$\sum_{k\geq1}e^{-\pi^{2}k/\log\left(q\right)}k^{\alpha}=\textrm{Li}_{-\alpha}\left(e^{-\pi^{2}/\log\left(q\right)}\right)$$ where $\textrm{Li}_{a}\left(z\right)$ is the polylogarithm function.

ADDENDUM. Maybe it's useful to note that this form of the Stirling's approximation of $\left|\Gamma\left(x+iy\right)\right|$ holds if $x_{1}\leq x\leq x_{2}
 $ for some $x_{1},x_{2}
 $ and $\left|y\right|\rightarrow\infty.
 $

Comment: Thank you for proving the convergence of the series. And I am going the pursue the value of the sum :D

Comment: @robit I added the sum of the series.

Comment: Fine approximation!

Comment: Thx again for add up the series. And $\log q$ 's sign doesn't matter because $  \left| \Gamma(m+2\pi ik/\log q) \right| = \left|  \Gamma(m-2\pi ik/\log q)  \right|$   : D